# "PERSISTENT_COMMAND_TIMEOUT and PERSISTENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT must be set to 600 seconds "

Tags: ansible

I'm writing a playbook to test cisco nexus switch upgrade using ansible. i'm using 'nxos_install_os' module to define the task. while i execute i see an error message

> PERSISTENT_COMMAND_TIMEOUT and PERSISTENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT must be set to 600 seconds.

I did change command_timeout and connection_timeout in ansible.cfg file to 1800 seconds as well as i change the connection: local to network_cli, so that i can define those timeout values in the playbook too. below is the playbook that i have, i still see that same error. is there anything that i am missing?

```
- hosts: Switch
  connection: network_cli
  vars:
   ANSIBLE_PERSISTENT_COMMAND_TIMEOUT: 1800
   ANSIBLE_PERSISTENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT: 1800
   ansible_network_os: nxos

  tasks:

     - name: Install OS on N9k
       check_mode: yes
       nxos_install_os:
             system_image_file: system_bin
             kickstart_image_file: kickstart.bin
             issu: desired
       ignore_errors: yes
       register: output
```

> "PERSISTENT_COMMAND_TIMEOUT and PERSISTENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT must be set to 600 seconds "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I regret that the error message is so opaque, but it seems from [reading the fine manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/plugins/connection/network_cli.html#parameters) that the actual `vars:` name is `ansible_command_timeout`, but regrettably it looks like there is no var for the connect timeout. You'll have to specify it in your `ansible.cfg`.

However, based on:

> I did change command_timeout and connection_timeout in ansible.cfg

I'm guessing that you either did not place them in the correct sections, or you are running ansible from a directory other than the one containing `ansible.cfg`

Based on the docs, I would expect `ansible.cfg` to contain:

```
[persistent_connection]
command_timeout = 1800
connect_timeout = 1800
```

Comment: I'm having my ansible.cfg file and the playbook in the same directory. good correction on the connect_timeout under vars. i have them set to a higher value but i have a # in front of connect_timeout.                                         [persistent_connection]
#connect_timeout = 3000
command_timeout = 3000
removed the # and executed. i no more see error. thx                                           [persistent_connection]
connect_timeout = 3000
command_timeout = 3000